# what is the use of creating ResourceURL in Portlet class?

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 CE for Portal Application development .
I am new to Liferay , so please excuse if my question is wrong .

I see that for using AJAX Requests in Liferay , we need to use ResourceURL .

Now my question is , I see a lot of examples in internet , where they are creating ResourceURL in Java Class using .

```
ResourceURL chartUrl = renderResponse.createResourceURL();
```

So please tell me what is the use of creating ResourceURL in Portlet class ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ResourceURL has been introduced in JSR-286 standards to make an ajax call.

In liferay if you say on click of any link if you want to perform any action and page should not get refresh.

Define a link and and provide resource url to it. In your class file implement logic by mapping resource action and your data will get rendered to portlet without page refresh.